# How to insert create customer account form layout to a block as a widget

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, customer-account, static-block

I want to insert `customer_account_create.xml` content which containing the create customer account form into one of my block that I created from

**backend > content > blocks > add new block**

Is there a way to do this?